# openstack autopilot is failing

Tags: juju, maas, cloud, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I'm trying autopilot test drive with vmware. No matter how many times I tried, it is failing to deploy openstack service activities like keystone, nova, and glance. Finally, it is hanging on:

`Creating a Landscape admin user`

for a long time before failing the installation completely. I see that landscape is able to control the nodes through MAAS, and also finished 80% openstack installation activities successfully. What am I missing here? I followed the steps exactly same as described in the installation document. How should I proceed in resolving this [issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kr9Wv.png)?

Comment: Logs and screenshots are added in Launchpad. If it is allowed, I can post that link here.

Comment: Please do [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/732486/edit) your question, including those screenshots

Answer (score 1):

This is bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/charms/+source/ceilometer-agent/+bug/1535062.

I believe a new VMware image has been made available for download at https://landscape.canonical.com/downloads/